# Lab environment for testing routing in a Unix environment?

Tags: networking, routing, testing

I know there are tools such as GNS3 and Packet Tracker; but the big problem with these tools is they do not work with open source tools such as OpenBGPD and BIRD.

So, this leads me to the question; what are some ways to test routing that work with tools such as OpenBGPD and BIRD without building an actual physical network to do the testing?

Comment: One way to do it might be to create a few virtual machines in VirtualBox.  Do read the docs about VirtualBox network options first.

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want to do.  For __simple__ routing tests, I'd say virtual boxes on one or two physical machines with plenty of RAM would be largely enough.  For penetration tests and the like, you might need a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this at first using `libvirt` with a VLAN that was not NATing; unfortunately, it was still having issues so I abandoned that method.

I found [CORE](http://www.nrl.navy.mil/itd/ncs/products/core) network emulation software; which allows me to drop in routers, switches, hubs, PCs for testing.

All in all, I was able to do full end to end testing using BIRD BGP with this software; definitely a good find.